# writing to text file multiple times android

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

i using this function:

```
> private void writeToFile(String data) {
>     try {
>         OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("mywords.txt",
> Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
>         outputStreamWriter.write(data);
>         outputStreamWriter.close();
>     }
>     catch (IOException e) {
>         Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
>     }  }
```

i want to write a lot of times and every time i write it changes like deletes all and adds new thing i write but i do not want it to delete

husky thanks i do not know why you deleted your comment it works i changed to MODE_APPEND

another problem how do i do space in the text file

Comment: read the doc for `openFileOutput`. In particular, the possible values of the parameters.

Comment: what space do you want to have? If you want space as a character try `data + " "`, or if you want to enter a line each time you write in file, just try `println` instead of `write`, or `data + "\r\n"`

Comment: you right im dumb i did it in wrong place for some reason tnx

Answer (score 2):

Pass `true` as the second argument to `FileOutputStream` to open the file in append mode.

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new FileOutputStream("mywords.txt", true), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is not specifying a valid location, try using getFilesDir() to obtain the directory the original was using.

Answer (score 0):

OutputStreamWriter by default overwrites. In order to append information to a file, you will have to give it additional information in the constructor. See also [OutputStreamWriter does not append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336623/outputstreamwriter-does-not-append) for more information.

Comment: im new started 2weeks ago is there a diffrent code to write i just found this one never did writing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  private void writeToFile(String data) {


    File file = new File("mywords.txt");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

        // Writes bytes from the specified byte array to this file output stream 
        fos.write(data.getBytes());

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while writing file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        // close the streams using close method
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
        }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Not going to work, no valid location has been specified

Comment: @Chris I tested the code, what do you mean by valid location?

Comment: its not working i using an activity that do write then this activity close and opens and writes again mybe this thwe problem?

Comment: No allowed directory has been specified.  Perhaps you tested this on a jvm in conditions where the working directory happens to be writable; it seems unlike you tested it on android.