# openFileInput reading only 1 line

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-file

I am accessing a file from my fragment in my Android app.
But my problem is that only 1 line of that file is being read.

My code is:

**FragmentTab2.java**

```
package com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab2.xml
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);

        TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.optext);

        try
        {
            FileInputStream fIn = getActivity().openFileInput("sample_details.txt");
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line =  null;
            String str = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                str += line;
            }

            txt.setText(str);

            bufferedReader.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("File not found.",e.toString());
        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

The code which writes the file (in a different fragment) is:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view == getView().findViewById(R.id.button1))
        {
            //Call all the elements of this Fragment here becuase they are accessible easily through
            //getView(); method. Use the getText(); method to get the Text and toString(); to convert
            //it.
            String name = ((EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String email = ((EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();

            if(name.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot store empty values !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream fOut = getActivity().openFileOutput("sample_details.txt", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                    outputStreamWriter.write(name + " " + email + ";");
                    Log.e("String Concat Done", "Concatenation of the Strings is done to write in the File. Write Success.");
                    outputStreamWriter.flush();
                    Log.e("Flush","Flush Success");
                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                    Log.e("Stream Closed","Both Streams are flushed and closed");

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAILED !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Error in File Write",e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know the correct way of implementing this.
Please let me know in detail how to do it, because I am new to Android.

Thanks.

Comment: First, my suspicious is that even if your code reads multiple lines, it may not *display* that as multiple lines, but rather as one unit of text.  Next, consider using the run-as tool of the adb shell, or the emulator where adb runs as root, in order to examine the private storage file and so figure out if the problem is in the reading or the writing.  Or temporarily add External Storage permission and move the file there where you can examine it, or on a more recent platform, use the package-specific permission-free external storage directory.

Answer (score 0):

Because your

`FileOutputStream fOut = getActivity().openFileOutput("sample_details.txt", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);`

should be

`openFileOutput(yourFile, Context.MODE_APPEND);`

`FileOutputStream` also have a constructor where you can append to the original file if you don't have context to be used with Android's `openFileOutput()` instead.

Extra reference for similar questions: [OutputStreamWriter does not append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336623/outputstreamwriter-does-not-append)

Comment: Will you please give the constructor code as well? Thanks.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);`

Instead of using that, you only need to change your current method to `FileOutputStream fOut = getActivity().openFileOutput("sample_details.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);`